# Add Files/Images as custom option to existing Order

Tags: custom-options

I am trying to attach a file / image to an existing order item as Option.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(863);
$predefinedOption = array(
'type' => 'image/tiff',
'title' => 'test',
'quote_path' => '\media\'.$image,
'order_path' => '\media\'.$image,
'fullpath' => Mage::getBaseDir() .'\'. $image,
'secret_key' => substr(md5(file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir() .'\'. $image)), 0, 20));

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

   $oldOptions = unserialize($item->getProductOptions());
   $newOptions = array_push($oldOptions['options'],$predefinedOption);
   $item->setProductOptions(serialize($newOptions));
   $item->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
   $item->save();
   $order->save();
   break;
}
```

But it does`nt work. I can work with additional_options to add a text as option, but not the image itself. My target is to give the shop admin the possibility to download the file / image directly from the order grid.

may i need to add the option also to the quote item? Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Add a custom option to a product, upload a file and have a look on the quote item in the database how it is saved. And yes/no/ahh... You ONLY have to add the file to the quote_item and be sure to transfer it later to the order_item (and maybe back to the quote_item for reorder)

Comment: That means, that i have to add the image/file before the quote item is converted to order item? Now i am listening on sales_order_place_after event. in this case the quote item already converted. Maybe its too complicated for this small feature. May i set a link to the file with the addtional_options field..

Comment: oh no, you can connect the file directly to the order item if this is no problem for you.